# Swiftui swipe down to dismiss modal works in Portrait but not Landscape

Tags: swift, swiftui, swipe, drag, dismiss

I was wondering if anyone knows a way to enable a simple swipe down to dismiss a modally presented view in swiftui when the device is in landscape orientation.

I have a button that pops up a modal view, and when in portrait mode on the iPhone it easily allows the user to swipe down and push that modal view down and away.  When rotating the device to landscape mode, that simple way to dismiss the view is disabled.  Supporting both landscape and portrait is a requirement of my app.  I understand this may be because of how the new versions of IOS handle landscape vs portrait, but was wondering if landscape could be set to function in a similar manner.  I do like that the image is full screen when presented, but a swipe down to dismiss is required as well.  I started writing my own custom drag gestures, but was thinking there might be an easier way.

Here is how the view is presented.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) {
            FullScreenImage(presentedAsModal: self.$presentingModal, selectedPattern: self.$selectedPattern) 
}
```

Comment: As I see - it is feature, by intended design: sheet in Portrait & full-screen in Landscape. If you want different, yes, custom implementation is a right way.

Comment: Darn. It stinks writing a bunch of extra code when the functionality is already built in, but unless I hear otherwise I guess this is how it has to be.